# Tracking online users using a Database with Python

Tags: python, database, sql-insert

I changed my database to include a 0/1 variable if the user is on the variable will be changed to 1 and changed to a 0 if the user closes the window/disconnects.

this is how the database was established

```py
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
    userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    user_on INTEGER(20) NOT NULL);
    ''')
```

This is the code I am attempting to use in my login function.

```py
               find_user_lite = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?")
                cursor.execute(find_user_lite,[(username)])
                if cursor.fetchall():
                    on_state = int(1)
                    change_state = ("UPDATE user SET user_on = ? WHERE username = ?")
                    cursor.execute(change_state,[(on_state),(username)])
```

When I click the login button, I have a seperate `server.py` that runs most of the database administration like viewing the database, creating new users, etc.

When I attempt to run the function that displays the current users nothing gets displayed except a `[]`.
[gyazo.com](https://gyazo.com/2fe0bbdfef6487d71ae463cfdeaf80cb)

Here is the function that displays the current online users:

```py
def display_users():
    with sqlite3.connect("apc.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_on")
    print(sum(cursor.fetchall()))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: But what's the problem that you're facing? Please provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you post the relevant sections from your code?

Comment: @MaverickDavidson: Works for me, get `[]` if `user_on == 0` and `[(1, 'test', '12345', 1)]` if `user_on == 1`

Comment: @stovfl Where exactly are you making this change? Is my change_state variable correct?

Comment: @MaverickDavidson: I use your `change_state = ` query and **all** query from your Question.

Comment: @stovfl So what you’re saying is that my code should work? Or is there something I need to change?

Comment: @MaverickDavidson: *"my code should work?"*: **YES**

Comment: @stovfl then why is my code not changing the users state when I login?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191610/discussion-between-maverick-davidson-and-stovfl).